# select option load changed when select

Tags: javascript, ajax

how to fill select option with data json

```
[{
    "user_id": "113",
    "employe_first_name": "Asaladauangkitamakan",
    "employe_last_name": "Nasibb"
}, {
    "user_id": "105",
    "employe_first_name": "Ryan",
    "employe_last_name": "Friday"
}, {
    "user_id": "87",
    "employe_first_name ":"hendi ",
    "employe_last_name ":"kenther"
}
```

]

and when i select change, fill another text field with employe_first_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it
html

```
<select id='test'>
    <option value='default'>chose user</option>
</select>
<input id='get_employe_first_name' type='text' />
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [{ "user_id": "113", "employe_first_name": "Asaladauangkitamakan", "employe_last_name": "Nasibb" }, { "user_id": "105", "employe_first_name": "Ryan", "employe_last_name": "Friday" }, { "user_id": "87", "employe_first_name ":"hendi ", "employe_last_name ":"kenther" } ];
    $.each(data,function(i,item){
        $("#test").append("<option value='"+item.user_id+"' employe_first_name='"+item.employe_first_name+"'>"+item.employe_first_name+" "+item.employe_last_name+"</option>");
    });
    $("#test").change(function(){
        $("#get_employe_first_name").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("employe_first_name"));
    });
});
```

or see demo
[jsfiddle.net/haduythuan/JFnD6/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/haduythuan/JFnD6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [ {"user_id":"113","employe_first_name":"Asaladauangkitamakan","employe_last_name":"Nasibb"}, {"user_id":"105","employe_first_name":"Ryan","employe_last_name":"Friday"},   {"user_id":"87","employe_first_name":"hendi","employe_last_name":"kenther"} ];
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = data[i].user_id;
        option.innerHTML = data[i].employe_first_name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(select);
select.onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById("txt").value = this.childNodes[this.selectedIndex].innerText;
};
```

Here's [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/rgaRL/2/)